# Php file called by ajax isn't echoing javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm trying to create a page where a user can upload a file and select the people they want to email it to. Once they click submit, I prevent page refresh and reset their inputs in the form. Now I want to place their previously entered information into a table on the same page (different section of the page).

Comment: You do not have a success function. But why not just return true or false and show or keep hiding

Comment: Well you do nothing with the response from the Ajax call. Also not a great idea to return JavaScript since you will have to val() it in the client which is not secure.

Comment: @epascarello I work with that afterwards, the code isn't relevant to what I'm trying to do which is why I didn't include it. Is there another way for me to display the table then?

Comment: @mplungjan I didn't include the success function here because it was working. And sorry how do you mean return true or false? Like where do I do that?

Comment: Return `{ "match" : true }` or `{ "match" : false }`  and check the response: `document.querySelector(".outputDiv").classList.toggle("hide",!response.match)`. Also getElementsByClassName returns a node list so you need `change[0].style.display = "block"` if you insist on returning javascript

Comment: Do I do the match part in php instead of what I had written before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did want to proceed with this concept, you would capture the output of the PHP script in a `done()` function, insert it in an element on the page, and run `eval()`. Like this...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../FileDrop/dbSystem.php",
    data: {tags: JSON.stringify(tags), file: 
          $('input[name=fileName]').val()};
}).success(function(result) {
  $( '#element' ).html(result);
  $( '#element script' ).each( () => { $(this).html().eval() }) 
});
```

But it would make alot more sense to return data that you use to execute the javascript in your page - that is, keep all that logic together rather than splitting some of it off into a PHP file.

```
<?php 
// php process that checks for 'valid'...
// create a json response
$output = array('valid' => 1);
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

.... and in your JS

```
.success(function(result) {
  // result is a stringified JSON object. We need to convert it into an actual JSON object with parse()
  result = JSON.parse(result);
  // might not matter, but result.valid will be a number which JSON converts into a string. By adding the + right before the variable, that tells JS to use it as a number for the comparison
  if (+result.valid == 1) {
    $(".outputDiv").show();
  }
});
```

Comment: The thing is, in my php file I am verifying if the user inputs match up with the database. If they do, then I want to display the table. That's why I'm a bit confused on how I should be outputting the js code. So would I capture the output and then using ajax, check if it's correct and insert table rows?

Comment: output the basic data needed to then feed into an if statement in your existing JS. I just updated my answer to show that onSuccess, if the right variable exists, you could just `$(".outputDiv").show();` - not sure if that answers your question

Comment: could you take a look at the answer I posted if you don't mind?

Comment: @ragin_lion - in general, it's a good practice to upvote or accept someone else's answer rather than copy and paste it into a new answer. To answer your question, determine the $valid variable in your PHP first, then just echo it back. You're only echoing back a message saying 'good to go' or 'not valid' and then letting your existing script take that message and show or hide the table cells.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to this so I didn't know. I did what you said and I'm echoing back 'valid' or 'invalid' and the ajax call is a success but I think if (result.valid == 'good to go') isn't working. Not sure if I wrote that incorrectly

Comment: I'm not sure where the disconnect is.. are you not sure how to check soemthing in the PHP? Or are you not sure what to do in the ajax on success? There are a few moving parts here, where are you getting confused?

Comment: I am unsure on the ajax success function..I want to check if the php variable $valid is returning 'good to go' but I'm not sure if I am writing it the correct way -> result.valid

Comment: @ragin_lion - I added some comments around my answer (the second part) - to try and show the way you echo the variable back and what your JS should do with it.

Comment: Thank you, that helped! I was able to make it work